# How to upload a file using active admin and carrier wave without mounting uploader on the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, rubygems

In my application, every product is downloadable. So when admin creates each product, he has to specify a file to be uploaded. Now I am planning to keep these files outside the website directory with product id as file names.

I am using active admin and carrierwave. I don't need to have a column in my products table for file path because given a product id, I know how to get that file. Because of this, in my `Product` model, I don't have a `mount_uploader` statement.

In active admin's product add page, I could show the file upload. But since it is not linked with the `Product` model, my uploader will never get called. I am wondering what is the best way to solve this problem? All I need is just upload the file and don't update anything in the model.

Any help would be great!